# 100% confidence interval for mean

Tags: confidence-interval

Is it possible to apply the law of the iterated logarithm (e.g. http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_iterated_logarithm) to derive non-trivial (i.e. bounded) 100% confidence intervals for population averages?

An abstract (http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1080/10485250410001713963) gives at least such hint. However, its first reference by Robbins (http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aoms/1177696786) does not seem to cover such result, as pointed out in @whuber's comment.

Edit: After justified comments by @whuber, I reformulated the question.

Comment: You need to say more about the context and the assumptions. Non-trivial 100% confidence intervals are usually impossible to achieve except when sampling from finite populations.

Comment: Could you tell us precisely where the Robbins paper discusses "100% confidence intervals"?  I could find no such reference in it, but maybe I overlooked something.

Comment: You are right, I also can't find it. I was following this reference from http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1080/10485250410001713963 (only abstract).

Answer (score 2):

100% confidence is only feasible if you have a bounded distribution or if you have sampled all members of the population (and then it becomes trivial for that distribution).

Comment: That's also what I think. But I don't understand why the LIL is mentioned in one of above mentiones articles as basis to form such 100% c.i. I see the LIL's usefulness in sequential c.i.s

Comment: Michael, are you perhaps misreading 100% *power* as 100% confidence?

Comment: As a technical note, 100% confidence can be achieved in many other circumstances. For instance, suppose the underlying set of distributions consists of all Normal$(\mu, 1)$ distributions with $-1\le \mu\le 1$. Then $[-1,1]$ is a 100% confidence interval for $\mu$ (regardless of the data). The point is that the kind of boundedness that is relevant here is that of the *parameter* rather than of the support of the *distribution.*

Comment: Another example where a nontrivial 100% CI can be found is in sampling from a finite population. For instance, suppose a population of three elements is known to have a mean between 0 and 100.  You sample one element and find it equals 150.  You now know with 100% confidence that the mean is between 50 and 100, even though it is not the case that "you have sampled all members of the population."

Comment: @whuber: thats look somewhat bayesian, it is not frequentist in the usual sense, since it is conditional on obtaing that special observation ...

Comment: @Kjetil I don't know of any useful CI that is not conditional on obtaining data!

Comment: @whuber well yes, but the coverage probability is usually computed pre-data, so cannot be conditional on obtaining some specific data value. There are some conditional theories, though.

Comment: Thank you, @Kjetil: I now see your point.  The distinction you are making is between a confidence interval *procedure* and the amount of *post hoc* "confidence" one can have in special cases. But my example was intended in the latter sense: a $100\%$ CI based on observing $X$ is $[X/3,\min(100,(200+X)/3)]$. Provided the population is not identically $(0,0,0)$, this has positive probability of being narrower than the interval $[0,100]$ we would use before observing $X$. In this sense it is non-trivial. This is not a Bayes interval: it assumes no prior distribution.