# 100% confidence interval

Tags: statistical-significance, mathematical-statistics

Is it possible to produce a 100% confidence interval for a sample mean?

Or does a 100% confidence interval imply that it is no longer a sample mean; that the population mean is already known?

Comment: It sounds like you really want to ask about a **$0\%$** confidence interval, not a $100\%$ interval. Regardless, whatever size you stipulate has nothing to do with whether you know the population mean.

Comment: "Or does a 100% confidence interval imply that it is no longer a sample mean; that the population mean is already known?" Can you clarify what you mean by this? My first reading of this was the same as @whuber: that you are interpreting "100% confidence" to mean "I am completely sure the mean is $\mu$", which isn't what a "100% confidence interval" would usually mean. Without some clarification on this point, it isn't clear what kind of answer you are expecting.

Comment: The answer to this question might help you: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/107655/100-confidence-interval-for-mean

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate; see.[here 1](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/107655/100-confidence-interval-for-mean) or [here 2](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/167830/how-to-estimate-100-confidence-interval-aka-what-is-the-z-value-of-standard-no).

Comment: If you had the entire population, you could have a 100% CI for the mean consisting of a single point, but then the usual models for the distribution (such as the normal) would not hold (they require an infinite population for the distributional model to apply).

Answer (score 1):

If you are some parametric test, that assumes normal distribution, then your 100% confidence interval will be from -infinity to + infinity. If you are using permutation test, then your confidence interval is bounded by number of samples

Comment: In the case of the permutation test it will generally then *not* be a 100% confidence interval.

Comment: yes, that's what I meant. Your maximum confidence is dependent on number of samples you are permuting, p value cannot be 0